# How to embed PYZ.-00.pyz_extracted folder with entry .py file to generate exe file?

Tags: assembly, pe, python, crackme, exe

I have decompiled exe using pyextractor script and generated 
these files:

```
PYZ-00.pyz
PYZ-00.pyz_extracted
gui
pyi_rth_tkinter
pyi_rth_multiprocessing
pyi_rth_pkgres
pyi_rth_win32comgenpy
pyiboot01_bootstrap
pyimod01_os_path
pyimod02_archive
pyimod03_importers
struc
```

I know that gui is the entry file. 
After updating header of gui , decompiled it to gui.py file.
(my process is similar to this one 
https://hshrzd.wordpress.com/2018/01/26/solving-a-pyinstaller-compiled-crackme/)

**My question is how to generate exe file so that it contains all the files from PYZ-00.pyz_extracted folder?**

Answer (score 1):

You can extract some file from .exe using pyi-archive_viewer, modify them and put back. But be attention, all files in .exe are compressed using DEFLATE (zlib.compress() - you can watch this in source code of PyInstaller). So, when putting back you need compress file to the exact size, that was when you extracted it.

Comment: Hi van, and welcome to RE.SE! Although your answer does seem to cover most of the question, I think it could quite benefit additional information and details, if you feel like doing that. Regardless, thanks for sharing your knowledge and I hope we see you more :)